# How to draw a rectangle from user input using WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, shapes

I want the user to enter the width and height of the rectangle and I want the rectangle to appear immediately after numbers have been entered. I don't want to have to push any buttons to have the rectangle appear.

I had the rectangle code working when I entered numbers for the height and width but when I changed it to variables from the user input textbox, nothing appears on the screen.

Here's my XAML:

```
TextBox Text="{Binding xcoord, Mode=OneWay}" Name="x" Grid.Row="1" Height="20" Width="40" Grid.Column="2"></TextBox>

TextBox Text="{Binding ycoord, Mode=OneWay}" Name="y" Grid.Row="2" Height="20" Width="40" Grid.Column="2"></TextBox
```

Here's my C#:

```
 public FEModel()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        CreateARectangle();        

    }

private double xval;

public double xcoord
{
    get { return xval; }
}

private double yval;

public double ycoord
{
    get { return yval; }
}

public void CreateARectangle()
{
    // Creates a Rectangle  
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
    rect.Height = ycoord;
    rect.Width = xcoord;
    // Create a Brush  
    SolidColorBrush colorbrush= new SolidColorBrush();
    colorbrush.Color = Colors.Red;
    colorbrush.Opacity = .3;
    SolidColorBrush blackBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
    blackBrush.Color = Colors.Black;
    // Set Rectangle's width and color  
    rect.StrokeThickness = 1;
    rect.Stroke = blackBrush;
    // Fill rectangle with color  
    rect.Fill =colorbrush;
    // Add Rectangle to the Grid.  
    can.Children.Add(rect);
}
```

I expect the rectangle to appear on the canvas as soon as the user enters x and y coordinates but instead, nothing happens.

Comment: Do you have any event handlers on the textboxes or where the users enters the values? Also, please add your XAML :)

Comment: Just updated it...had to remove some brackets so that the website would recognize it. Sorry I'm a newbie haha.

Comment: How are you calling CreateARectangle? I don't see anyway for your problem to see when the users inputs anything new or when the variables change

Comment: Just updated again..sorry..thought I had all relevant info in there the first time.

Comment: Why are the `xcoord` and `ycoord` properties read-only? Add setters and call the `CreateARectangle()` method in these.

Comment: So I did this:  public partial class FEModel : Page
    {
        public double xval;
        public double yval;

        public double xcoord
        {

            get { return xval; }

            set
            {
                xcoord = xval;
                CreateARectangle();
            }
        }
    

        public double ycoord
        {
            get { return yval; }

            set
            {
                yval = ycoord;
                CreateARectangle();
            }
        }

Still nothing appears inside the canvas.

Comment: Your bindings should be TwoWay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use two way binding for your text boxes.

Here is a fully working sample.

Window Xaml: Note that the default update trigger for textbox is 'LostFocus'. In my example i set to 'PropertyChanged' so the rectangle updates as soon as the user changes a value.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp9.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp9"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Name="can">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding xcoord, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Name="x" Height="20" Width="40" Margin="40,51,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ycoord, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Name="y" Height="20" Width="40" Margin="40,81,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here is the code behind. I changed the code to adjust the rectangle size rather than creating a new rectangle every time the values are changed.

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApp9
{

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;      
        }

        private double xval = 50;

        public double xcoord
        {
            get=> xval; 
            set
            {
                xval = value;
                CreateARectangle();
            }
        }

        private double yval = 50;

        public double ycoord
        {
            get => yval;
            set
            {
                yval = value;
                CreateARectangle();
            }
        }
        Rectangle rect = null;
        public void CreateARectangle()
        {
            if (rect == null)
            {
                // Creates a Rectangle  
                rect = new Rectangle();
                rect.Height = ycoord;
                rect.Width = xcoord;
                // Create a Brush  
                SolidColorBrush colorbrush = new SolidColorBrush();
                colorbrush.Color = Colors.Red;
                colorbrush.Opacity = .3;
                SolidColorBrush blackBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
                blackBrush.Color = Colors.Black;
                // Set Rectangle's width and color  
                rect.StrokeThickness = 1;
                rect.Stroke = blackBrush;
                // Fill rectangle with color  
                rect.Fill = colorbrush;
                // Add Rectangle to the Grid.  
                can.Children.Add(rect);
            } 
            else
            {
                rect.Height = ycoord;
                rect.Width = xcoord;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As a side note you can also create the rectangle in XAML, directly binding to the textbox values.

```
    <TextBox Text="50" Name="x" Height="20" Width="40" Margin="10,10,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox Text="50" Name="y" Height="20" Width="40" Margin="10,35,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.017,-0.629"/>
    <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Fill="#4CFF0000" Margin="60,5,0,0" Width="{Binding ElementName=x, Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="{Binding ElementName=y, Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```